# I am selecting a radio button using javascript but radio button is not highlighting

Tags: jquery, html, magento-1.7

I have a group of radio buttons which i am displaying in rows. In this groups i am selecting any 1 radio button using `jQuery` but not able to highlight it yet it acts like it is selected as checked="checked" in `HTML` while `firebugging`.

Need Help!

```
$('input[type=radio][value='+ value + ']').attr("checked","checked");
```

OR

```
$('input[type=radio][value='+ value + ']').prop("checked",true);
```

I tried both above.
note i am not using a `<form>` element.

Comment: Can you give us some code? JsFiddle perhaps so we can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if there is no multiple radio buttons with same name and value on the document

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.prop()` for this

```
$('#CheckboxID').prop('checked', true);
```

You can also use `.attr()` too

```
$('#CheckboxID').attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: I have try both
$('input[type=radio][value='+ value + ]').attr("checked","checked");
$('input[type=radio][value='+ value + ]').prop("checked",true);

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
$("input[type='radio'][value='"+ value + "']").prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: That works , but not in my code i think there is some confliction

Comment: If you need anymore clarifications, please do ask me..I can make it to work.